# Problems with Elementary on ASUS laptop

Tags: release-juno, display, sound, resolution

first, I would like to apologize. I am not an experienced Linux user. However, I used to run Ubuntu Linux on my computer.

I recently wanted to try something new and fast and snappy as Elementary OS. The problems appears when I boot up my Elementary OS from USB and then click on Try Without installing. The speakers start buzzing. It sounds like a weird static noise that will not stop. Even full installation does not help.

The second problem is with the resolution. Only choice I have in my system is 800x640 and system can not detect my laptop screen.

The last problem is with the terminal. I have tried to get some update via sudo apt-get update and so on. It does not allow me to do anything due to insecure(8) manpage repository error.

My laptop is ASUS Zenbook 14 UM431DA (Ryzen 5 3500U and 8GB RAM).

I just want to mention that I do not have any sound or resolution problem with Ubuntu, that works perfectly fine.

Is there anyone who could help me with this issue ?

Comment: Did you install any PPA or program? That may be causing the repository error. To solve the resolution and audio problems you could try updating your kernel with `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 && sudo apt dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo dpkg --purge linux-generic-hwe-18.04 && sudo apt autoremove`

worked for me.

Comment: sudo dpkg --purge linux-generic-hwe-18.04 && sudo apt autoremove solve problem. work fine